# Need Help Setting UIPicker's Label From Selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker with a UILabel above it that updates displaying the current selection.

When I go to this view the 2nd time, the UIPicker's selection is on the last cell where I left off, but the label is on the default string.  How can I make it so the label is also on where I last left off?

This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)displayPicker
{
    self.numberLabel.text = @"1 number";
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    self.numberButtonText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ number", [self.pickerArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    self.numberLabel.text = self.numberButtonText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i assume correct, you are calling

`-(void)displayPicker`

to set the default numberLabel text value (as in `self.numberLabel.text = @"1 number";`).

Possible cause would be, 
that *- (void)displayPicker* is called every time, the view is presented to the user, but

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

is not.

You might want to check for such behavior, by inserting some `NSLog()` statements and perhaps correct it by using something like this:

```
- (void)displayPicker
{
    self.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i number", 
                            [self.numberPicker selectedRowInComponent: 0 ]];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think I need something like that, or maybe I can just call `- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component` from `(void)displayPicker`?

Comment: Try, it's the best way to find out.